# Can't load a .deployproj file in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

[Visual Studio Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62wiX.png)

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac. All the investigation I've done so far says that it comes with everything necessary to work with Azure. However, every time I try to open a solution that contains a project with the extension ".deployproj" I keep getting an error message saying:

> Error while trying to load the project '/Users/marco/Documents/sync1.nosync/Sync1.LOS/src/Sync1.LOS.Azure/Sync1.LOS.Azure.deployproj': Unknown solution item type

From what I can read about Azure projects, Visual Studio needs the Azure Development tools and it is included in the installer, but this is for Windows. Visual Studio for Mac installer includes .Net Core, packages for Android, Xamarion, iOS among others. What I've read is that it includes the necessary tools for Azure, but I still have this issue.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the present time there is no support for .deployproj files in Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: Mmmm... I was afraid someone was gonna say that haha. Thank you very much for clarifying this for me @MattWard

Comment: but why?, hahaha its 2021 still no support.